# JSON deserialize throwing exception

Tags: c#, json

I am using C# code to deserialize json and write to a datatable. I run into error when json has null.

***JSON***

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "Id": 456895,
      "Name": "Chelsea - Arsenal",
      "BetOffers": {
          "BetType": "Game",
          "Pick": "1",
          "Odds": 1.15
            }
    },
    {
      "Id": 456879,
      "Name": "Liverpool - Manchester United",
      "BetOffers": {
          "BetType": null,
          "Pick": "1",
          "Odds": null
            }
    },
    {
      "Id": 9101112,
      "Name": "Arsenal - Manchester United",
      "BetOffers": {
          "BetType": null,
          "Pick": "1",
          "Odds": null
            }
    },
        {
      "Id": 13141516,
      "Name": "Liverpool - Chelsea",
      "BetOffers": "not accepting"
    },
    {
      "Id": 123456,
      "Name": {
                "game": "Chelsea - Liverpool",
                "gameurl": "http://game.com/api/game/adfgfm"
            },
      "BetOffers": {
          "BetType": "Game",
          "Pick": "1",
          "Odds": 1.15
            }
    }
  ]
}
```

***C#***

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BetOffer BetOffers { get; set; }
}
public class BetOffer
{
    public string BetType { get; set; }
    public string Pick { get; set; }
    public double Odds { get; set; }
}
public class MyRootObject
{
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

        try
        {
            string jsonstring;
            var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyRootObject>(jsonstring);

            string connectionString = "";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BetType", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Pick", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Odds", typeof(string)));
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < root.events.Count; i++)
            {
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["ID"] = root.events[i].ID;
                    dr["Name"] = root.events[i].Name;                      
                    dr["BetType"] = root.events[i].BetOffers.BetType;
                    dr["Pick"] = root.events[i].BetOffers.Pick;
                    dr["Odds"] = root.events[i].BetOffers.Odds;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
}
```

***Error:*** Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I am trying to look for a way to fix this issue instead having to check using an if(root.events[i].BetOffers.Odds == null) condition.

Answer (score 4):

BetOffer.Odds is double. It cannot accept null.

Using double? can help.

```
public class BetOffer
{
    public string BetType { get; set; }
    public string Pick { get; set; }
    public double? Odds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Farzan Hajian, Thank you for the response. The problem is its just not the Odds any value could be null. For instance the string BetType could be null. Then how do we fix that. Make the non-nullable value type to nullable.

Comment: I figured out the issue with the json string not sure how to deserialize jagged array with unknown dimensions. Updated the original post with new json.

Comment: Hi @pbj , Other types you are using (string, BetOffer) are nullable except for Id and I guess it does not make any sense to have a null Id, so it does not cause any problem.
The hard part is Event.Name. Since it must receive both string and an custom object, you have to define it as a JObject ( public JObject Name { get; set; } ).

Comment: And what do you mean by deserializing jagged array? There is no jagged array.

Comment: Hi @Farzan Hajian, My bad it's a string and complex object. Could you guide me on how to parse Event.Name.

Comment: Hi @pbi. Check https://gist.github.com/FarzanHajian/ee3fbf3ff0961a07b67ae1d2af97ae40  but I highly recommand to have a rigid JSON structure. This degree of flexibility is no easy to handle

Answer (score 0):

should you use "?" after the data type.

```
  public class BetOffers    
  {
    public string BetType { get; set; } 
    public string Pick { get; set; } 
    public double? Odds { get; set; } 
  }
```

If you do not understand, please refer to the following [document](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/csharp2/nullable.html#:%7E:text=C%23%20provides%20language%20support%20for,same%20type%20as%20Nullable%3CSystem.)

Comment: Was there any point in adding this answer after an hour, considering its nearly an exact copy of the previous answer just with less explanation and not as well formatted ?